# Same query plan of AGE and different stacktrace (PostgreSQL version 15 & 16)

Tags: database, postgresql, apache-age

Currently I am working on an issue that happens on PostgreSQL server version 16 and does not happen with the 15 version (alongside Apache AGE).

The issue happens when executing the OPTIONAL MATCH query which lead to a LEFT-JOIN
Both queries have the same PLAN but they does not execute the same stack trace

The query is as the following:

```sql
SELECT * FROM cypher('cypher_match', $$
    MATCH (u:opt_match_v)
    OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[m]-(l)
    RETURN u.name as u, type(m), l.name as l
$$) AS (u agtype, m agtype, l agtype);
```

Adding **EXPLAIN** before **MATCH** to get the query plan, returns at both versions almost the same with changes in the ids of the label ids and etc. but they are the same steps

```sql
 Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..73536354.30 rows=69969 width=96)
   Join Filter: (((m.start_id = (age_id(_agtype_build_vertex(u.id, _label_name('124289'::oid, u.id), u.properties)))::graphid) AND (m.end_i
d = l.id)) OR ((m.end_id = (age_id(_agtype_build_vertex(u.id, _label_name('124289'::oid, u.id), u.properties)))::graphid) AND (m.start_id =
 l.id)))
   ->  Seq Scan on opt_match_v u  (cost=0.00..22.00 rows=1200 width=40)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..14632.13 rows=1166171 width=96)
         ->  Append  (cost=0.00..28.00 rows=1201 width=40)
               ->  Seq Scan on _ag_label_vertex l_1  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=40)
               ->  Seq Scan on opt_match_v l_2  (cost=0.00..22.00 rows=1200 width=40)
         ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..29.41 rows=971 width=56)
               ->  Append  (cost=0.00..24.56 rows=971 width=56)
                     ->  Seq Scan on _ag_label_edge m_1  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=56)
                     ->  Seq Scan on opt_match_e m_2  (cost=0.00..19.70 rows=970 width=56)
(11 rows)
```

Given a break-point at **_label_name** function which has the problem that throws an error on pg16

**At first entry of**

The stack trace of PG15

```c
age.so!_label_name(FunctionCallInfo fcinfo) (age-16/src/backend/catalog/ag_label.c:190)
ExecInterpExpr(ExprState * state, ExprContext * econtext, _Bool * isnull) (postgresql-15.3/src/backend/executor/execExprInterp.c:1262)
ExecEvalExprSwitchContext(_Bool * isNull, ExprContext * econtext, ExprState * state) (postgresql-15.3/src/include/executor/executor.h:341)
ExecProject(ProjectionInfo * projInfo) (postgresql-15.3/src/include/executor/executor.h:375)
ExecScan(ScanState * node, ExecScanAccessMtd accessMtd, ExecScanRecheckMtd recheckMtd) (postgresql-15.3/src/backend/executor/execScan.c:238)
ExecProcNode(PlanState * node) (postgresql-15.3/src/include/executor/executor.h:259)
ExecAppend(PlanState * pstate) (postgresql-15.3/src/backend/executor/nodeAppend.c:347)
ExecProcNode(PlanState * node) (postgresql-15.3/src/include/executor/executor.h:259)
ExecNestLoop(PlanState * pstate) (postgresql-15.3/src/backend/executor/nodeNestloop.c:109)
ExecProcNode(PlanState * node) (postgresql-15.3/src/include/executor/executor.h:259)
ExecNestLoop(PlanState * pstate) (postgresql-15.3/src/backend/executor/nodeNestloop.c:160)
ExecProcNode(PlanState * node) (postgresql-15.3/src/include/executor/executor.h:259)
ExecutePlan(_Bool execute_once, DestReceiver * dest, ScanDirection direction, uint64 numberTuples, CmdType operation, _Bool use_parallel_mode, PlanState * planstate, EState * estate) (postgresql-15.3/src/backend/executor/execMain.c:1636)
standard_ExecutorRun(QueryDesc * queryDesc, ScanDirection direction, uint64 count, _Bool execute_once) (postgresql-15.3/src/backend/executor/execMain.c:363)
PortalRunSelect(Portal portal, _Bool forward, long count, DestReceiver * dest) (postgresql-15.3/src/backend/tcop/pquery.c:924)
PortalRun(Portal portal, long count, _Bool isTopLevel, _Bool run_once, DestReceiver * dest, DestReceiver * altdest, QueryCompletion * qc) (postgresql-15.3/src/backend/tcop/pquery.c:768)
exec_simple_query(const char * query_string) (postgresql-15.3/src/backend/tcop/postgres.c:1250)
PostgresMain(const char * dbname, const char * username) (postgresql-15.3/src/backend/tcop/postgres.c:4593)
BackendRun(Port * port) (postgresql-15.3/src/backend/postmaster/postmaster.c:4511)
BackendStartup(Port * port) (postgresql-15.3/src/backend/postmaster/postmaster.c:4239)
ServerLoop() (postgresql-15.3/src/backend/postmaster/postmaster.c:1806)
PostmasterMain(int argc, char ** argv) (postgresql-15.3/src/backend/postmaster/postmaster.c:1478)
main(int argc, char ** argv) (postgresql-15.3/src/backend/main/main.c:202)
```

The stack trace of PG16

```c
age.so!_label_name(FunctionCallInfo fcinfo) (age-6/src/backend/catalog/ag_label.c:190)
ExecInterpExpr(ExprState * state, ExprContext * econtext, _Bool * isnull) postgresql-16/src/backend/executor/execExprInterp.c:734)
ExecEvalExprSwitchContext(_Bool * isNull, ExprContext * econtext, ExprState * state) postgresql-16/src/include/executor/executor.h:355)
ExecQual(ExprContext * econtext, ExprState * state) postgresql-16/src/include/executor/executor.h:424)
ExecNestLoop(PlanState * pstate) postgresql-16/src/backend/executor/nodeNestloop.c:214)
ExecProcNode(PlanState * node) postgresql-16/src/include/executor/executor.h:273)
ExecutePlan(_Bool execute_once, DestReceiver * dest, ScanDirection direction, uint64 numberTuples, CmdType operation, _Bool use_parallel_mode, PlanState * planstate, EState * estate) postgresql-16/src/backend/executor/execMain.c:1661)
standard_ExecutorRun(QueryDesc * queryDesc, ScanDirection direction, uint64 count, _Bool execute_once) postgresql-16/src/backend/executor/execMain.c:365)
PortalRunSelect(Portal portal, _Bool forward, long count, DestReceiver * dest) postgresql-16/src/backend/tcop/pquery.c:924)
PortalRun(Portal portal, long count, _Bool isTopLevel, _Bool run_once, DestReceiver * dest, DestReceiver * altdest, QueryCompletion * qc) postgresql-16/src/backend/tcop/pquery.c:768)
exec_simple_query(const char * query_string) postgresql-16/src/backend/tcop/postgres.c:1274)
PostgresMain(const char * dbname, const char * username) postgresql-16/src/backend/tcop/postgres.c:4632)
BackendRun(Port * port) postgresql-16/src/backend/postmaster/postmaster.c:4461)
BackendStartup(Port * port) postgresql-16/src/backend/postmaster/postmaster.c:4189)
ServerLoop() postgresql-16/src/backend/postmaster/postmaster.c:1779)
PostmasterMain(int argc, char ** argv) postgresql-16/src/backend/postmaster/postmaster.c:1463)
main(int argc, char ** argv) postgresql-16/src/backend/main/main.c:198)
```

As we see they are different starting from the call `ExecutePlan`
At `ExecNestLoop` The following `ExecProcNode` at line 160 is being called in pg15 while in pg16 it does not

```c
        innerTupleSlot = ExecProcNode(innerPlan);
```

**What makes the stack-trace of the same query plan is different?**

References:

- https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v16beta1/
- https://github.com/muhammadshoaib/age/tree/dev/PG16

##### Reproduce

- Assumes having installed PostgreSQL and Apache AGE

```sql
LOAD 'age';
SET search_path TO ag_catalog;

SELECT create_graph('cypher_match');

SELECT * FROM cypher('cypher_match', $$
    CREATE (:opt_match_v {name: 'someone'})-[:opt_match_e]->(:opt_match_v {name: 'somebody'}),
           (:opt_match_v {name: 'anybody'})-[:opt_match_e]->(:opt_match_v {name: 'nobody'})
$$) AS (u agtype);

SELECT * FROM cypher('cypher_match', $$
    EXPLAIN MATCH (u:opt_match_v)
    OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[m]-(l)
    RETURN u.name as u, type(m), l.name as l
$$) AS (u agtype, m agtype, l agtype);
```

Results of pg15:

```sql
     u      |       m       |     l      
------------+---------------+------------
 "someone"  | "opt_match_e" | "somebody"
 "somebody" | "opt_match_e" | "someone"
 "anybody"  | "opt_match_e" | "nobody"
 "nobody"   | "opt_match_e" | "anybody"
(4 rows)
```

Results of pg16:

```sql
ERROR:  graph_oid and label_id must not be null
```

Answer (score -2):

The difference between stacktraces of PG 15 and 16 is due to the internal changes in query execution.
The error is telling that there is an issue with `graph_oid` and `label_id` in PG 16 because they are **null**, but this issue was not in PG 15.

So you need to check for AGE modifications and difference between source code of PG 15 and 16